# Use SharedArrayBuffer and atomics for large array of objects shared by Node processes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that contains 100,000 objects. Each object has a property that contains a digital signature. The signatures are generated using Crypto. https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign

Currently, I have ten (10) forked processes running on Node.js that each take 10,000 of the objects and processes them independently of each other. The processing involves verifying the digital signatures and updating them, which takes to much time on a single process (which is why I'm using workers). The original array is split into ten separate arrays and is written to disk. The worker processes read their respective portion from disk (currently using JSON format).

I am wondering if it would be possible to use SharedArrayBuffer and atomics and share the array among the ten processes so that I do not have to write all this data to disk? Node 9.0.0 now includes SharedArrayBuffer and atomics support, however there is almost no documentation on this: http://node.green/#ES2017-features-shared-memory-and-atomics-SharedArrayBuffer

Comment: seems a bit green still. you could just use a ramdisk to make it almost as fast in the meantime.